# Script which disable inheritance

Tags: powershell

I need help with powershell script. Unfortunately i have never use powershell and now i neet to write script which disable inheritance i group of 1,5k folders. Structure of this folders look like  Parent_folder\Child_folder_1_to_N \Under folders. I need turn off inheritance only in child folder1_to_N without chenging inheritance in underfolders. I found some scripts in google but they not work or work not like i want and im to big noob to chenge it. Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, is twofold:

1. Assess: Write a script that uses Get-ChildItem to retrieve every folder and for each folder $_.GetAccessControl() and see if specific ACLs are set. If it's the case, fix it.
2. Control: If things look good in 1. just control how you delegate administrative rights at the top folders. Inheritance will just ensure everything is fine at the lower levels.

I can't help more.